# Installing fonts from terminal instead of Font Book?

Tags: terminal, command-line, install, font, font-book

I know how do install new fonts using Font Book.

Is there also a way to install fonts from the terminal, using some smart shell command?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can simply copy them into `/Library/Fonts` (for system wide use) or `~/Library/Fonts` (for use by current user).

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer works in MacOS 14.0. Fonts need to be validated and activated before they can be used in other apps. I noticed some extra files in the fonts directories, but am a bit hesitant to edit them directly.

Comment: @JackGoossen I can’t reproduce that at all. Dropping them into `~/Library/Fonts` works for me in 14.1 (currently in beta) as it always has.

Comment: @user137369 You are right, I just re-checked again on 14.0 and it seems to work. The font only shows up in Pages if I select 'Format > Fonts > Show Fonts', not in the drop down list in the format pane, maybe that got me confused.

Comment: The font when dropped to `~/Library/Fonts` does not show up in fonts selection anywhere, nor in the "Font Book" app. Using macOS 13.6 (Ventura).
Any steps to refresh or make them visible (preferably via Terminal, of course)?

Answer (score 4):

Install fonts with the following terminal command (replace `BRLNSR` with your font):

```
cd ~/Library/Fonts && { 
    curl -O 'https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/ResumeBuilder/blob/master/fonts/src/main/resources/frankhassanabad/com/github/windowsfonts/BRLNSR.TTF'
    cd -; }
```

This code does the following:

1. `cd` into the fonts directory
2. `curl` downloads the font
3. pops back to the original directory

This relies on the very nice [fonts github repo](https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/ResumeBuilder/tree/master/fonts/src/main/resources/frankhassanabad/com/github/windowsfonts) from Frank Hassanabad with a bunch of fonts stored - but you could change the curl url to wherever the font you want is located online.

The clever way the `cd` into a directory, download and pop out again came from user [Atle's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2269047/atle) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362402/save-file-to-specific-folder-with-curl-command).

Answer (score 1):

By manually copying to a fonts folder used to be the only way to install fonts before Font Book was introduced. (barring 3rd party sw)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your startup file (e.g. ~/.zshrc):

```
alias fontbook="open -b com.apple.FontBook"
```

Then, in a new Terminal, you can execute:

```
fontbook *.otf
```